# Prove the inequality of edge number, $||H||\leq||H_1||+||H_2||$

Tags: graph-theory

I am trouble understanding the inequality of edge number, $||H||\leq||H_1||+||H_2||$ at [p13](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/books/graph.theory/preview/Ch1.pdf).

$||G||$ is the number of edges of G.
$\{H_1,H_2\}$ is a separation of $H_1$. 
$G[U]$ is induced subgraph of G by U.

If we separete $H$ into $H_1,H_2$,we lose the edge which have end points on both $H_1$ and $H_2$.

So, I feel $||H||\geq||H_1||+||H_2||$ is rather correct.

Why $||H||\leq||H_1||+||H_2||$ ?

Comment: By "$\{H_1,H_1\}$ is a separation of $H_1$" did you mean "$\{H_1,H_2\}$ is a separation of $H$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said

> if we separete $H$ into $H_1,H_2$, we lose the edge which have end points on both $H_1$ and $H_2$.

This is your mistake. $H_1$ and $H_2$ are not disjoint, they meet at $H_1\cap H_2$, with $\vert H_1\cap H_2\vert \leq k$. So that you there are no edges from $H_1\setminus H_2$ to $H_2\setminus H_1$, and you do not miss any edges.

However when summing $\vert\vert H_1\vert\vert + \vert\vert H_2\vert\vert$ you are counting twice the edges inside $H_2\cap H_1$, That is why you have 
$\vert\vert H\vert\vert\leq\vert\vert H_1\vert\vert + \vert\vert H_2\vert\vert$

In total you should have,
$$\vert\vert H\vert\vert = \vert\vert H_1\vert\vert + \vert\vert H_2\vert\vert - \vert\vert G[U_1\cap U_2]\vert\vert$$

**Note:** it would be nice to make your question independent from any link as much as possible. Maybe next time try to put definitions and some explanations directly here.